# unable to insert data into mysql database

Tags: php

to save my web crawler position that how many pages it crawled i try to save them it in database so that next time it start from the position where it was stoped

first i have table checkpoint with 2 columns id and check

my first step is to get old position from database and store it in $i

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM checkpoint" ) or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
while($ch_me = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $i=$ch_me["check"];
            echo "<br>i value in loop ".$i;
            break;  // need just first check value in db
}
```

next i have to increment $i value and have to update it into database

```
while(1)
{   // doing work 
    $i++;
    // save i value in database
    mysql_query("UPDATE `checkpoint` SET `id`=1,`check`=$i WHERE 1");
```

}

now problem i a facing is with update query ... it cant update $i value to databse ????? strage it was working for first time then when i run next time , not working

Comment: "Can't update" is not a built-in error message in either PHP or MySQL.

Comment: `while(1) { .. }` that's infinite loop and nowhere you stooping it. Your code is total mess

Comment: what kind of while statement is the 2nd one?????

Comment: it can stop ...... while(1)  {   if( limit == 10) exit(0);}        sorry i not mention it

Comment: i figure out problem is with database got error when i executed the query directly in phpmyadmin              Duplicate entry '1' for key 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where in update missing

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM checkpoint limit 1" ) or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
$ch_me = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$i=$ch_me['check'];
$id = $ch_me['id'];
$i+=1;

mysql_query("UPDATE checkpoint SET check=$i WHERE id=$id");
```

Comment: I have pointed out that update query is wrong. On what basis do you want to update?

Comment: getting error:;    Duplicate entry '1' for key 1    // what that mean i have jsut simple table   id and check      id=1 and check=0

Comment: That error means that you have already an id with value 1 which is unique. So you can't duplicate it. Why are you updating id? Is it an auto_increment field or not?